# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_hdf'

Tags: python, hdf5

I am running following code which imports csv files and append all data into single DATA array. But while storing this array into HDF5, I am keep getting  error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_hdf'. 
Please help me understand what I am missing.

```
import pandas as pd
import h5py
import glob
import os

path = "Z:\Test Data"
def get_CSV_files(path):
    results = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            fileExt=os.path.splitext(file)[-1]
            if fileExt.lower() == '.csv':
                results.append(os.path.join(root, file))
        for directory in dirs:
            results += get_CSV_files(os.path.join(root, directory))
    return results

def store_all_data_hdf5(path):
    files = get_CSV_files(path)
    DATA=[]
    for file_name in files:
        data = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(file_name, sep="\t")
        DATA.append(data)
    store = pd.HDFStore('STORE.h5')
    DATA.to_hdf('STORE.h5','table', append=True)
    store.close()
    return DATA
```

Comment: Makes sense to me. `DATA` is a list, and lists don't have a `to_hdf` method. Incidentally, I notice that pandas DataFrames _do_ have a `to_hdf` method. Maybe try calling it on a dataframe instead?

Comment: What do you try to achieve by line ``DATA.to_hdf('STORE.h5','table', append=True)`` ? DATA is a list, so it won't have this Attribute. Didn't you want something around the lines of ``store.to_hdf(DATA)``?

Answer (score 0):

DATA is a list you define by - `DATA=[]` and it does not have attribute `to_hdf`.

You can find some example of how to use pandas `HDFStore` [here](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/101333/pandas.HDFStore)

And you would probably need something like -

```
def store_all_data_hdf5(path):
    files = get_CSV_files(path)
    DATA=[]
    store = pd.HDFStore('STORE.h5')
    for file_name in files:
        data = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(file_name, sep="\t")
        DATA.append(data)
        store.put('my_file', data, append=True)
    store.close()
    return DATA
```